# Is there any way, given user permission, for an android app to start on its own at a scheduled time in the future?

Tags: android, alarm

As the title suggests, is there any way to have an Android application be schedule to start on its own at some time in the future. For example, is it possible within the Android API for a developer to write an application that might initiate at 7am if previously scheduled by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Alarm Manager.

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow
>   you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the
>   future.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html